# How to make jQuery change html on completion of .animation()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make the header of my animation change depending on whether the object is currently being animate. For instance, when mario is animating to a users click, it should read "he is walking", and once he has reached his destination, it should read "he is standing still". From what I understand from the jQuery API documentation, the complete property should take care of this.

[jQuery .animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stage.css" />

    <script src="jslibs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stage").click(function (event) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var x = event.pageX - offset.left;
        var y = event.pageY - offset.top;

        $("#header").html("<h1>Mario is walking!</h1>");

        $("#player").animate({
            top: y,
            left: x,
            duration: 3,
            complete: function () {
                $("#header").html("<h1>Mario is standing still...</h1>");
            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Mario is standing still...</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="stage">
        <img id="player" src="images/mario.gif" alt="Mario" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These changes work correctly. When duration is grouped with options, it is not recognized. This debugs correctly.

```
$( "#player" ).animate({
top: y,
left: x,
duration: 3
},{
complete: function(){ 
$( "#header" ).html( "<h1>Mario is standing still...</h1>" ); 
}
});
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting errors, is nothing happening? Please explain the actual problem you're having a bit more.

Comment: I'm sorry, everything is happening correctly, except the header change back to standing still.

Comment: Your `complete` function changes the header to 'standing still...' so it should change back. Before you try to debug further first make sure you update your code to peoples' answers below using the correct arguments for jQuery's `animate()`

Answer (score 1):

Your params to the animate function is wrong, you need to use the variation that takes [properties and options](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) arguments.

The css definitions are the properties where as things like `duration` and `complete` are the options

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stage").click(function (event) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var x = event.pageX - offset.left;
        var y = event.pageY - offset.top;

        $("#header").html("<h1>Mario is walking!</h1>");

        $("#player").animate({
            top: y,
            left: x
        }, {
            duration: 3,
            complete: function () {
                $("#header").html("<h1>Mario is standing still...</h1>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3RpQh/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to simply use the callback function for animation, as shown on the website you linked.  Their Example:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
   $( "#book" ).animate({
  opacity: 0.25,
  left: "+=50",
  height: "toggle"
 }, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
});
```